# How to use 'in' a python match case statement

Tags: python, python-3.10, structural-pattern-matching

I'd like to check if a value is in a list in the 'case' of a structural pattern matching.

Put it another way, I'd like to translate the following "if else" in a match case statement.

```
list1 =  [4, 2, 7]
var = 2
if var == 1:
    print("case1")
elif var in list1:
    print("case2")
```

The following code does not work but shows what I would like to do:

```
list1 =  [4, 2, 7]
var = 2
match var:
    case 1:
        print("case1")

    case in list1 : # Not working
        print("case2")
```

Comment: Don't you just want an [OR pattern](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/#or-patterns)? I'd recommend running through the tutorial, which covers this too: https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#or-patterns

Comment: I have a list in input. I guess it could work if you have a one-line that converts list in ORs but I also wanted to know if it was supported by python.

Comment: Then see further down the tutorial, which covers conditions more broadly: https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#adding-conditions-to-patterns

Comment: I came up with this solution " case _ if var in list1:" and as my question has been closed I conclude that 'contained in a list' is not supported in Python 3.10 structural pattern matching. I hope it will be in the future because it's not that "arbitrary" to me. It's pretty basic.

Comment: Moreover, I consider the closing of my question unjustified.  Please don't redirect  any question about features not (yet) supported to that question.  A better answer to my original question would have been "This feature is not (yet) supported but you can use  match case with arbitrary condition" without closing it. Never mind.